# All particles get deleted when one life ends

Tags: javascript, arrays, particles

https://jsfiddle.net/zwkdf0cg/12/

```
class Emitter {
    constructor(settings) {
        for (let key in settings) {
            this[key] = settings[key];
        }
        this.particle = undefined;
        this.parts = [];
    }

    grab_parts(particle_settings) {
        this.particle = particle_settings;
        return this.particle;
    }

    load_parts() {
        if (this.counters.rate >= this.rate) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.particles.max; i++) {
                this.parts.push(new Particle(this.particle));
            }
            this.counters.rate = 0;
        }
        this.counters.rate += this.timer();
    }

    draw_parts() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.parts.length; i++) {
            let p = this.parts[i];
            let can = this.canvas;
            let con = this.context;

            con.beginPath();
            con.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            let gradient = con.createRadialGradient(p.x, p.y, p.radius, p.x, p.y, 0);
            gradient.addColorStop(0,'hsla(20, 80%, 50%, 0)');
            gradient.addColorStop(1,'hsla(20, 80%, 50%, 0.5)');
            con.fillStyle = gradient;
            con.fill();            
        }
    }

    update_parts() {
        let can = this.canvas;
        let con = this.context;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.parts.length; i++) {
            let p = this.parts[i];
            if (p.x < -5 || p.x > can.width || p.y < -5 || p.y > can.height || p.counters.life < 0) {
                let s = this.parts.splice(i, 1);
            } else {
                this.parts[i].update();
            }
        }        
    } 
}



class Particle {
    constructor(settings) {
        for (let key in settings) {
            this[key] = settings[key];
        }
        this.initialize = {
            angle: false
        }
        this.life.range = number_range(this.life.min, this.life.max);
        this.counters.life = this.life.range;
    }

    update() {
        if (!this.initialize.angle) {
            this.angle = radians(number_range(160, 180));
            this.initialize.angle = true;
        }
        this.x += 1 * Math.cos(this.angle);
        this.y += 1 * Math.sin(this.angle);

        this.counters.life -= this.timer();        
    }
}
```

I set the particle's life to be a number between 2 and 8 whenever it gets created. In the particle's update() method, called from the emitter's update_parts() method, it's life counter is reduced by it's timer() property which returns the time passed since the last update. The emitter's update_parts() method has a condition that will splice the particle from the emitter's parts[] array if it is out of bounds or it's life is < 0. Whenever a single particle's life is < 0, all the particles on the screen get spliced and I can't figure out why. I have tried reversing the iteration of the array, creating a new array with only the living particles and assigning the emitter's parts[] array to this, flagging the dead particles and creating a new function to delete them after the update_parts() is called and random tweaking. I had some trouble with the way I passed the particle_settings object into the particle's constructor but I don't know if these are related. ET phone home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is to blame:

```
for (let key in settings) {
    this[key] = settings[key];
}
```

As you pass `counters` object there, it is not copied, but shared between the instances.

Check the [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/zwkdf0cg/13/) using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s `cloneDeep` instead:

```
_.assign(this, _.cloneDeep(settings));
```

`_.assign` assigns the properties to `this` similar to your original code.
`_.cloneDeep` performs a deep copy of the `settings` object.

Answer (score 0):

you're calling `.splice()` on the array that you're iterating over, which is a Bad Idea; `splice()` [changes the size of the array it's called on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) so your loop's test condition won't always work like you think it should.  What happens if you replace the `for()` loop in `update_parts()` with this:

```
this.parts = this.parts.filter(function(part) {
  // filter out the ones we don't want...
  return !(p.x < -5 || p.x > can.width || p.y < -5 || p.y > can.height || p.counters.life < 0);
}).forEach(function(part) {
  // ...and update the rest
  part.update();
});
```